# how can i remove minutes from hours in r? for example i have 23:45 and i want to have 23 only NOT 23:00, how can i do that in r

Tags: r

i have a big dataset with our 1000s recodes and i want to remove minutes from hours. how can i do that in r? i have just run the first 6.

```
> finaldat<-cbind(data1.2,var3,var2,var1)
> head(finaldat)
        DATE  TIME                          PLACE ZONE TYPE.OF.CRIME WEEK day
1 2011/01/01 23:00 KIEPIES CLUB                   <NA> ARMED ROBBERY    1   1
2 2011/01/03 10:00 AUSSPANNPLATZ                    14 ARMED ROBBERY    1   3
3 2011/01/07 14:00 UNAM BUSHES                      16 ARMED ROBBERY    1   7
4 2011/01/08 21:34 TOTAL SERV. STATION, KHOMASDAL    9 ARMED ROBBERY    1   8
5 2011/01/15  <NA> WOODPALM STR 625                 11 ARMED ROBBERY    2  15
6 2011/01/03 14:03 C KANDOVAZU STR                   5   ASSAULT GBH    1   3
  month year
1     1 2011
2     1 2011
3     1 2011
4     1 2011
5     1 2011
6     1 2011
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove everything after colon (`:`)

```
finaldat$HOUR <- sub(':.*', '', finaldat$TIME)
```

For example,

```
sub(':.*', '', '23:45')
#[1] "23"
```

Another option is to convert to `POSIXct` and extract the hour.

```
finaldat$HOUR <- format(as.POSIXct(finaldat$TIME, format = "%H:%M"), "%H")
```

You might want to add `as.numeric`/`as.integer` to convert `HOUR` into number.